# Image is clickable and does desired change but after first-click cannot be clicked again

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, imageview, actionlistener

I have tried different methods in regards to changing the program to be operational but do not fully understand Events. I am attempting to make a memory game thus the desired functionality is after initial click I can re-click the image with a conditional statement that allows me to check if images match. Any help regarding reaching this desired result is greatly appreciated.

I believe this amount of code is sufficient, if otherwise please state.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.image.Image ;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;




public class memGameDriver extends Application {

    Stage window;
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    ImageView imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree,imageFour,imageFive, imageSix,imageSeven, cardBack;
    ImageView imageReplace;

    easyDifficulty easyGame = new easyDifficulty(imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree, imageFour);

    String baseUrl = easyGame.getGSD();
    String wrongUrl = easyGame.getWrongUrl();

    Random randomGen = new Random();


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        System.out.println("What difficulty?");
        String difficulty = scan.nextLine();

        makeWindow(primaryStage);

        makeGrid();

        startGame(difficulty);
        //System.out.println(numClicks);


        showWindow();

    }

    //Window
    public void makeWindow(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        this.window = primaryStage;
        this.window.setTitle("GSD Memory Game");
    }

    public void showWindow()
    {
        Scene scene = new Scene(this.grid,450,500);
        this.window.setScene(scene);
        this.window.show();
    }

    //Grid
    public void makeGrid()
    {
        this.grid.setPadding(new Insets(50,50, 50, 50)); // add padding to grid
        //Vertical and Horizontal gap
        this.grid.setVgap(50);
        this.grid.setHgap(50);
    }

    //Game
    public void startGame(String difficulty)
    {
        if(difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("easy"))
        {
            easy();
        }
        else if(difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("medium"))
        {
            medium();
        }
        else if(difficulty.equalsIgnoreCase("hard"))
        {
            hard();
        }

    }
    //Game difficulties
    public void easy()
    {

        int randNum = randomGen.nextInt(4)+1;
        int x = 0;

        Label title = new Label("Welcome to GSD Memory!");
        GridPane.setConstraints(title, 0 ,0);


        if(randNum == 1) {
            setOne();
        }
        else if(randNum == 2){
            setTwo();
        }
        else if(randNum == 3)
        {
            setThree();
        }
        else
        {
            setFour();
        }



        grid.getChildren().addAll(title,imageOne, imageTwo, imageThree, imageFour);


    }





    private void setFour() {


        //Display Card backs
        imageOne = createCardBacks(imageOne);
        imageTwo = createCardBacks(imageTwo);
        imageThree = createCardBacks(imageThree);
        imageFour = createCardBacks(imageFour);

        //Set grid location
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageOne, 0, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageTwo, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageThree, 0, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageFour, 1, 2);
        //



         imageOne.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {


            imageReplace = flipToCard(imageOne);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 0, 1);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageOne = flipBack(imageOne);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageOne, 0, 1);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageOne);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
            //imageOne.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            /*

              //  event.consume();
            //});
               */

        });
        imageTwo.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToWrong(imageTwo);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 1, 1);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageTwo = flipBack(imageTwo);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageTwo, 1, 1);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageTwo);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });
        imageThree.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToCard(imageThree);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 0, 2);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageThree = flipBack(imageThree);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageThree, 0, 2);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageThree);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        y.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });
        imageFour.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToWrong(imageFour);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 1, 2);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageFour = flipBack(imageFour);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageFour, 1, 2);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageFour);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        y.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });

    }

    private void setThree() {


        //Display Card backs
        imageOne = createCardBacks(imageOne);
        imageTwo = createCardBacks(imageTwo);
        imageThree = createCardBacks(imageThree);
        imageFour = createCardBacks(imageFour);

        //Set grid location
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageOne, 0, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageTwo, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageThree, 0, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageFour, 1, 2);
        //

        imageOne.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {


            imageReplace = flipToCard(imageOne);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 0, 1);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageOne = flipBack(imageOne);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageOne, 0, 1);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageOne);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
            //imageOne.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            /*

              //  event.consume();
            //});
           */

        });
        imageTwo.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToWrong(imageTwo);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 1, 1);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageTwo = flipBack(imageTwo);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageTwo, 1, 1);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageTwo);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });
        imageThree.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToWrong(imageThree);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 0, 2);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageThree = flipBack(imageThree);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageThree, 0, 2);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageThree);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        y.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });
        imageFour.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToCard(imageFour);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 1, 2);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageFour = flipBack(imageFour);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageFour, 1, 2);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageFour);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        y.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });

    }

    private void setTwo() {



        //Display Card backs
        imageOne = createCardBacks(imageOne);
        imageTwo = createCardBacks(imageTwo);
        imageThree = createCardBacks(imageThree);
        imageFour = createCardBacks(imageFour);

        //Set grid location
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageOne, 0, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageTwo, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageThree, 0, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageFour, 1, 2);
        //
        imageOne.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {


            imageReplace = flipToWrong(imageOne);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 0, 1);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageOne = flipBack(imageOne);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageOne, 0, 1);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageOne);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
            //imageOne.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            /*

              //  event.consume();
            //});
        */

        });
        imageTwo.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToCard(imageTwo);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 1, 1);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageTwo = flipBack(imageTwo);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageTwo, 1, 1);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageTwo);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });
        imageThree.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToWrong(imageThree);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 0, 2);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageThree = flipBack(imageThree);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageThree, 0, 2);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageThree);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        y.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });
        imageFour.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToCard(imageFour);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 1, 2);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageFour = flipBack(imageFour);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageFour, 1, 2);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageFour);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        y.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });


    }

    private void setOne() {
        //Display Card backs
        imageOne = createCardBacks(imageOne);
        imageTwo = createCardBacks(imageTwo);
        imageThree = createCardBacks(imageThree);
        imageFour = createCardBacks(imageFour);

        //Set grid location
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageOne, 0, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageTwo, 1, 1);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageThree, 0, 2);
        GridPane.setConstraints(imageFour, 1, 2);
        //


        imageOne.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {


            imageReplace = flipToCard(imageOne);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 0, 1);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageOne = flipBack(imageOne);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageOne, 0, 1);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageOne);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
            //imageOne.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            /*

              //  event.consume();
            //});
      */

        });
        imageTwo.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToCard(imageTwo);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 1, 1);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageTwo = flipBack(imageTwo);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageTwo, 1, 1);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageTwo);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                        x.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });
        imageThree.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToWrong(imageThree);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 0, 2);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageThree = flipBack(imageThree);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageThree, 0, 2);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageThree);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        y.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });
        imageFour.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent e) -> {
            imageReplace = flipToWrong(imageFour);
            GridPane.setConstraints(imageReplace, 1, 2);
            grid.getChildren().add(imageReplace);

            Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(4000);

                        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                imageFour = flipBack(imageFour);
                                GridPane.setConstraints(imageFour, 1, 2);
                                grid.getChildren().add(imageFour);
                            }
                        });


                    } catch (InterruptedException y) {
                        y.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };

            Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
            thread.start();
        });

    }



    public void medium()
    {

    }

    public void hard()
    {

    }

    ImageView createCardBacks(ImageView image)
    {
        image = new ImageView("memoryGameImages//tileBack.jpg");
        image.setFitHeight(150);
        image.setFitWidth(150);
        return image;
    }

    ImageView flipToCard(ImageView image)
    {
        image = new ImageView(baseUrl);
        image.setFitHeight(150);
        image.setFitWidth(150);
        return image;
    }

    ImageView flipToWrong(ImageView image)
    {
        image = new ImageView(wrongUrl);
        image.setFitHeight(0b10010110);
        image.setFitWidth(150);
        return image;
    }

    ImageView flipBack(ImageView image)
    {

            image = createCardBacks(image);
            return image;


    }


    /*
    private class ActionListener extends Frame implements WindowListener, ActionListener()
    {

    } */



    /*


     });

     */



}
```

Comment: Hard to say without the flip methods, but I guess they create new `ImageView`s and stack more and more nodes on top of each other in the `GridPane`. The `flipBack` method probably doesn't register a listener... I recommend rewriting those listeners anyway since there's much duplicate code... Also if there's no animation involved simply replacing `ImageView` is enough to replace the image. No need to modify the children of the `GridPane`...

Comment: I added all the code to prevent hiccups like this - also thank you for the tip regarding imageview!Perhaps its the fact it stacks something over the other one preventing the proper functionality. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are only setting the mouse listener on the object the first time you create it:

```
imageOne.setOnMouseClicked(…
```

Then you throw away the ImageView object held in the imageOne field, by reassigning it:

```
imageOne = flipBack(imageOne);
```

flipBack is returning a *brand new* ImageView, which you are placing in the imageOne field.  You had called setOnMouseClicked for the ImageView originally held in imageOne, but you never called setOnMouseClicked for the new ImageView.

The best solution is to avoid creating new ImageViews.  You can change an existing ImageView’s image easily:

```
ImageView flipToCard(ImageView image)
{
    image.setImage(new Image(baseUrl));
    image.setFitHeight(150);
    image.setFitWidth(150);
    return image;   // return same ImageView, not a new one
}
```

Comment: It tells me that 'Image is abstract so it cannot be initialized' + thank you for taking the time to review it by the way.

Comment: You imported the wrong `Image` class.   You need to import [javafx.scene.image.Image](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html), not java.awt.Image.